# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass　のエラーが出ます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

今[「作ってわかるデータベース」](https://openbook4.me/projects/92/sections/496)の13章まで一通り読みました。
上記サイトの内容に従って、
`http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/show/ユーザID`をURLに打ち込むと、
そのユーザの、ユーザ名・ユーザID・ロケーションなどが表示されるページを作ろうとしているところです。
`undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`とエラーが出て解決できないです。
全くの初心者のため原因が推測できません。ご教授いただければ幸いです。

---

データベースのファイルseeds.rbのソースコード：

```
@user = User.new
@user.name = 'Ryo Suzuki'
@user.username = 'ryooopan'
@user.location = 'Kanagawa, Japan'
@user.about = 'Hello, I am Ryo. I am from database!'
@user.save

@user = User.new
@user.name = 'Shohei Aoki'
@user.username = 'moyahima'
@user.location = 'Tottori, Japan'
@user.about = 'Nice to meet you. I am from database!'
@user.save
```

コントローラusers.controller.rbのソースコード：

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
 def show
  @user = User.find_by(:username => params[:username])
  end
end
```

show.html.erbのソースコード：

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

 def show
  @user = User.find_by(:username => params[:username])
  end
end
```

Comment: まず、エラーはメッセージだけでなく、発生場所（ファイルや行番号）なども表示さます。それがないと、どこで何が発生しているのか読み取れず、デバッグは非常に難しいものになります。なので、できるだけエラーメッセージ全体を質問内容に追記してください。

Comment: あと、ぱっと見、`show.html.erb`のコードがコントローラのコードと同じなので、よくあるコピー＆ペーストミスと思われます。こういった注意不足によるのミスは、プログラミングでは即エラーになるので、見直しなどをしっかり行うことをおすすめします。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、コピー＆ペーストミスでした。コントローラを書き直すことで解決しました。